# How to set arguments of a resource with for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I am trying to create resource aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group, which loads the parameters from a list. I am trying to do that with for_each, but doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to achieve this? Here's what I have so far:

```
variable "parameters"       { type = list }
resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "db-aurora-postgresql-cluster-parameter-group" {
    ...
   parameter {
     for_each = { for par in var.parameters : par.name => par }
       name    = each.value.name
       value   = each.value.value
  }
}
```

My tfvars looks like this:

```
    parameters = [
      {
        name  = "timezone"
        value = "CET"
      },...
```

I get these errors:

```
    Error: each.value cannot be used in this context
    
      on resources.tf line 21, in resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "db-aurora-postgresql-cluster-parameter-group":
      21:     name    = each.value.name
    
    A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it is
    unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in
    its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your
    configuration to work around this error.
```

I also tried with `dynamic "parameter" {` but also doesn't work:

```
  dynamic "parameter" {
    for_each  = var.parameters
    name      = parameter.value["name"]
    value     = parameter.value["value"]
  }
```

```
    Error: Unsupported argument
    
      on resources.tf line 21, in resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "db-aurora-postgresql-cluster-parameter-group":
      21:     name    = each.value.name
    
    An argument named "name" is not expected here.
```

Comment: You want a `dynamic` block, not `for_each`: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided code, you need to use `dynamic`, but it seems you have been using it wrong:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "db-aurora-postgresql-cluster-parameter-group" {
...
  dynamic "parameter" {
    for_each = { for par in var.parameters : par.name => par }
    content {
      name  = parameter.value.name
      value = parameter.value.value
    }
  }
}
```